# Callin view's method once

Tags: java, android

What is the proper way to call view's method:

```
findViewById(R.id.btn_Foo).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

vs

```
Button fooBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Foo);
fooBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

As I understand correctly, as a general Java code efficiency rule, one should use variables. But in this case, what if the `view` method called only once - does it mean that calling `setVisibility` without defining a variable is more effcient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does it mean that calling setVisibility without defining a variable is more effcient?

Performance-wise, the efficiency of the two approaches are almost, if not completely, the same, if that's what you mean by "efficient".

If "efficient" means the time it takes to write the code, then of course the first approach is more efficient.

> But in this case, what if the view method called only once

As a general rule, when you want to use the foo button later in the code, you want to make it a variable. If you just want to use it once, it's fine to not declare a variable. However, **not needing to use an object twice *now* does not mean you won't need to use it again next month.** It is very possible that next month, you found a bug in your code or you want to add a new feature and now you need to use foo button twice. If you haven't declared `fooButton` as a variable a month ago, you would have to declare it now.

So unless you are 200% sure that foo button will never be used again in the same scope, make it a variable. It is a `View` after all, and you tend to refer `View`s very often.